# case operator on for operator

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement

```
for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
 case 0: cout << "0"<<endl;
 case 1: cout << "1"<<endl;
 case 2: cout << "2"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Why print `0 1 2 1 2 2` ? And not just `0 1 2`. I use gcc.

Comment: Your answer is in a [reference on `switch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch).

Comment: use a break statement after each case.

Comment: What prevented you from reading your C++ book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a switch case block, once a `case` is satisfied, the control of the program will stop checking to see if each other `case` is true and will continue to execute each "action".  For example:

```
int i = 1;
switch (i)
{
    case 0: 
        cout << "0"; //action 1
    case 1:
        cout << "1"; //action 2
    case 2:
        cout << "2"; //action 3
}

//output is 12
```

So, in your for loop, this is also happening.  To resolve this issue (as mentioned by others), use `break` statement at the end of each action to prevent the programming control from "falling through" each action:

```
int i = 2;
switch (i)
    {
        case 0: 
            cout << "0"; //action 1
            break;
        case 1:
            cout << "1"; //action 2
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "2"; //action 3
            break;
    }

    //output is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
{
  switch (i)
  {
   case 0: cout << "0"<<endl; break;
   case 1: cout << "1"<<endl; break;
   case 2: cout << "2"<<endl; break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `break;` after each piece of code in `case x:` like that

```
switch (i)
{
case 0: cout << "0"<<endl; break;
case 1: cout << "1"<<endl; break;
case 2: cout << "2"<<endl; break;
}
```

So, after the piece of code after `case` is executed, control goes to the `for` loop.